# На Android отличается цвет градиента и не грузится фон

Tags: css

Есть [страница](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/sms/MSIv2/). У футера, а также у многих других блоков задан градиент:

```
background: #1d1e21;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1d1e21, #121316);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1d1e21, #121316);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1d1e21, #121316);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#1d1e21, #121316);
background: linear-gradient(#1d1e21, #121316);
```

Но на Android-телефоне фон выглядит совсем по-другому, слишком темным (возможно и не только на Android, но и на iOS).
Также не грузится фон слайдера в самом верху. В чем может быть проблема?
В Android, или в CSS?

Comment: Сделай скриншот и стрелкой покажи что именно ты имеешь ввиду. А то совершенно непонятно ...

Comment: Проблема может быть в экране